# Make multiple enemies follow on trigger Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, navigation, artificial-intelligence, unityscript, path-finding

Right now I am making a timed "escape" themed game where the player must find pieces of their ship that have scattered upon crashing in order to get off the planet. The player must avoid the enemies that will end up chasing them throughout the level.

My current problem is figuring out how to get multiple enemies to follow once it is triggered.

Right now only the one follows but the other 5 in the area don't move. I was thinking about putting them into an array but I'm unsure if that will work as I need to access the navmeshagent component

Here is my code:

```
#pragma strict

//script by Kyle Crombie & Paul Christopher

    //will add negative action if collision is detected with player

var target : Transform; //the enemy's target 
var isSeen: boolean = false;

var agent: NavMeshAgent;

function OnTriggerStay() { 

    isSeen = true;
    target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform; //target the player

}

function Update () { 

    if(isSeen){
        agent.SetDestination(target.position);
    }

}
```

Comment: the language is called UnityScript, similar syntactically but otherwise different language

Comment: are you trying to get all the enemies to follow once any one of them are triggered?

Comment: also; the OnTriggerStay() function will activate when _anything_ collides with the trigger, I suspect you would want to check if the player object is the one within the trigger.... you can access the colliding object if you include the parameter in the function call, refer to the docs: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html you can then check "other.tag = "Player" " or something similar to check if it was the player colliding with the trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the type of the agent variable from NavMeshAgent to array of NavMeshAgent. In the editor you can set the size of the array and then assign all the enemies you want to react. Then you can iterate over them and update them all. This is what it looks like:

```
#pragma strict

//script by Kyle Crombie & Paul Christopher
//will add negative action if collision is detected with player

var target : Transform; //the enemy's target 
var isSeen: boolean = false;

var agents : NavMeshAgent[]; // This is now an array!

function OnTriggerStay() {
    isSeen = true;
    target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform; //target the player
}

function Update () {
    if(isSeen){
        for (var agent in agents) {
            agent.SetDestination(target.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could tag the enemies and use [FindGameObjectsWithTag](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) in combination with GetComponent. Then it looks like this:

```
#pragma strict

//script by Kyle Crombie & Paul Christopher
//will add negative action if collision is detected with player

var target : Transform; //the enemy's target 
var isSeen: boolean = false;

function OnTriggerStay() {
    isSeen = true;
    target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform; //target the player
}

function Update () {
    if(isSeen){
        for (var agent in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy")) {
            agent.GetComponent(NavMeshAgent).SetDestination(target.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the idea of using an array but I wasn't sure how to implement it! I'll give that a try later on! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to get it to track the distance from the player? Right now I have it with the first part of the code but I want to transport the player back to the start of the level (either by returning it to its original coordinate points or reloading the level). The only problem I'm getting is the the drone never actually gets close enough to actually collide even with the stopping distance set to zero.

Comment: The script is placed on a trigger near where the drones are located so if the player walks through it, the drones start to follow. Just not sure how to track the drones using the given for loop as I'm not accessing the transform position of each individual drone.

Comment: Within the for loop, you can test the distance from var agent to the player. Var agent changes to each of the drones during the loop.

Comment: Should I create a variable to store the distance and then test distance using an If statement? Such as:

 var distance: Number;

 if(distance < 3){
  application.LoadLevel("Level_2");
 }

Just trying to wrap my head around it as I get the gist but application is where I'm stuck

Comment: Yes, if you do that in the loop, then the level will be reloaded if any drone comes within that distance